# Trigger an R function from Google storage bucket?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

From this link https://code.markedmondson.me/googleCloudRunner/articles/usecase-r-event-driven-pubsub.html, it's possible to trigger an R function from pub/sub.

But does Google offer possibility to trigger an R function when a new file is uploaded to a bucket?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using EventArc and Cloud Run, see [Create a trigger for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/creating-triggers#direct-events).

> **NOTE** Cloud Run supports any runtime (that you can containerize) and -- although opinionated (constrained set of runtime versions), Cloud Functions next generation (`gen2`) creates Cloud Run services.

One other way to do this is less practical: [Cloud Storage triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) with Cloud Functions. R isn't a supported runtime for Cloud Functions and so, while not impossible,  I don't recommend this approach.

There are probably others, GCP's eventing is confusing and my take is that Google's supporting different approaches for customer continuity reasons and doesn't provide clear guidance on the best solutions for "green field" applications.

I think (!?) [Eventarc](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs) is the strategic solution and recommend using that if you can.

Comment: Hi with yours advices, a Pub/Sub message triggers my Cloud Run execution with EventArc. In Cloud Run (R script) I listen event with the library/function   googleCloudRunner::cr_plumber_pubsub(message, fct to execute). I would like to get environment context associated to the message. Is it possible?